# When I boot some words showed on screen,what do they mean?

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, brightness, kylin

The text is:
[    1.3087766] pci 0000:00:01.0 ASPM: Could not configure common clock

My pc is lenovo Y400,and OS is ubuntu kylin 14.04LTS(ubuntu for Chinese:-))
Intel corei5 3230M     NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M

And how can I get rid of them?I can't fix the brightness using methods I found on the Internet,do they have some relation?My English isn't very well but I think I have expressed the point:-)

PS:All things go well except that.